# Constraint based analysis: understanding the program $[[ \text{fn} \ x => [x]^1]^2 [ \text{fn} \ y => [y]^3]^4]^5$

Tags: functional-programming, constraint-satisfaction, static-analysis

I am currently studying the textbook [*Principles of Program Analysis* by Flemming Nielson, Hanne R. Nielson, and Chris Hankin](http://faculty.sist.shanghaitech.edu.cn/faculty/songfu/cav/PPA.pdf). Chapter **1.4 Constraint Based Analysis** says the following:

> **1.4 Constraint Based Analysis**
> The purpose of *Control Flow Analysis* is to determine information about what "elementary blocks" may lead to what other "elementary blocks". This information is immediately available for the $\mathrm{While}$ language unlike what is the case for more advanced imperative, functional and object-oriented languages. Often Control Flow Analysis is expressed as a Constraint Based Analysis as will be illustrated in this section.
> Consider the following functional program:
>
> ```
> let f = fn x => x 1;
>     g = fn y => y + 2;
>     h = fn z => z + 3
> in (f g) + (f h)
> ```
>
> It defines a higher-order function `f` with formal parameter `x` and body `x 1`; then it defines two functions `g` and `h` that are given as actual parameters to `f` in the body of the `let`-construct. Semantically, `x` will be bound to each of these two functions in turn so both `g` and `h` will be applied to `1` and the result of the computation will be the value $7$.
> An application of `f` will transfer control to the body of `f`, i.e. to `x 1`, and this application of `x` will transfer control to the body of `x`. The problem is that we cannot immediately point to the body of `x`: we need to know what parameters `f` will be called with. This is exactly the information that the Control Flow Analysis gives us:
> $$\text{For each function application, which functions may be applied.}$$
> As is typical of functional languages, the labelling scheme used would seem to have a very different character than the one employed for imperative languages because the "elementary blocks" may be nested. We shall therefore label all subexpressions as in the following simple program that will be used to illustrate the analysis.
> **Example 1.2** Consider the program:
> $$[[ \text{fn} \ x => [x]^1]^2 [ \text{fn} \ y => [y]^3]^4]^5$$
> It calls the identity function $\text{fn} \ x => x$ on the argument $\text{fn} \ y => y$ and clearly evaluates to $\text{fn} \ y => y$ itself (omitting all $[ \dots ]^\mathscr{l}$).
>
> We shall now be interested in associating information with the labels themselves, rather than with the entries and exits of the labels - thereby we exploit the fact that there are no side-effects in out simple functional language. The Control Flow Analysis will be specified by a pair $(\hat{C}, \hat{\rho})$ of functions where $\hat{C}(\mathscr{l})$ is supposed to contain the values that the subexpression (or "elementary block") labelled $\mathscr{l}$ may evaluate to and $\hat{\rho}(x)$ contain the values that the variable $x$ can be bound to.
>
> **The constraint system.** One way to specify the Control Flow Analysis then is by means of a collection of constraints and we shall illustrate this for the program of Example 1.2. There are three classes of constraints. One class of constraints relate the values of function abstractions to their labels:
> $$\{ \text{fn} \ x => [x]^1 \} \subseteq \hat{C}(2) \\ \{ \text{fn} \ y => [y]^3 \} \subseteq \hat{C}(4)$$
> These constraints state that a function abstraction evaluates to a closure containing the abstraction itself. So the general pattern is that an occurrence of $[\text{fn} \ x => e]^\mathscr{l}$ in the program gives rise to a constraint $\{ \text{fn} \ x => e \} \subseteq \hat{C}(\mathscr{l})$.
> The second class of constraints relate the values of variables to their labels:
> $$\hat{\rho}(x) \subseteq \hat{C}(1) \\ \hat{\rho}(y) \subseteq \hat{C}(3)$$
> The constraints state that a variable always evaluates to its value. So for each occurrence of $[x]^\mathscr{l}$ in the program we will have a constraint $\hat{\rho}(x) \subseteq \hat{C}(\mathscr{l})$.
> The third class of constraints concerns function application: for each application point $[e_1 \ e_2]^\mathscr{l}$, and for each possible function $[\text{fn} \ x => e]^{\mathscr{l}^\prime}$ that could be called at this point, we will have: (i) a constraint expressing that the formal parameter of the function is bound to the actual parameter at the application point, and (ii) a constraint expressing that the result obtained by evaluating the body of the function is a possible result of the application.
> Our example program has just one application $[[\dots]^2[\dots]^4]^5$, but there are two candidates for the function, i.e. $\hat{C}(2)$ is a subset of the set $\{ \text{fn} \ x => [x]^1, \text{fn} \ y => [y]^3 \}$. If the function $\text{fn} \ x => [x]^1$ is applied then the two constraints are $\hat{C}(4) \subseteq \hat{\rho}(x)$ and $\hat{C}(1) \subseteq \hat{C}(5)$. We express this as *conditional constraints*:
> $$\{ \text{fn} \ x => [x]^1 \} \subseteq \hat{C}(2) \Rightarrow \hat{C}(4) \subseteq \hat{\rho}(x) \\ \{ \text{fn} \ x => [x]^1 \} \subseteq \hat{C}(2) \Rightarrow \hat{C}(1) \subseteq \hat{C}(5)$$
> Alternatively, the function being applied could be $\text{fn} \ y => [y]^3$ and the corresponding conditional constraints are:
> $$\{ \text{fn} \ y => [y]^3 \} \subseteq \hat{C}(2) \Rightarrow \hat{C}(4) \subseteq \hat{\rho}(y) \\ \{ \text{fn} \ y => [y]^3 \} \subseteq \hat{C}(2) \Rightarrow \hat{C}(3) \subseteq \hat{C}(5)$$
> **The least solution.** As in Section 1.3 we shall be interested in the least solution to this set of constraints: the smaller the sets of values given by $\hat{C}$ and $\hat{\rho}$, the more precise the analysis is in predicting which function are applied. In Exercise 1.2 we show that the following choice of $\hat{C}$ and $\hat{\rho}$ gives a solution to the above constraints:
> $$\hat{C}(1) = \{ \text{fn} \ y => [y]^3 \} \\ \hat{C}(2) = \{ \text{fn} \ x => [x]^1 \} \\ \hat{C}(3) = \emptyset \\ \hat{C}(4) = \{ \text{fn} \ y => [y]^3 \} \\ \hat{C}(5) = \{ \text{fn} \ y => [y]^3 \} \\ \hat{\rho}(x) = \{ \text{fn} \ y => [y]^3 \} \\ \hat{\rho}(y) = \emptyset$$
> Among other things this tells us that the function abstraction $\text{fn} \ y => y$ is never applied (since $\hat{\rho}(y) = \emptyset$) and that the program may only evaluate to the function abstraction $\text{fn} \ y => y$ (since $\hat{C}(5) = \{ \text{fn} \ y => [y]^3 \}$).
> Note the similarities between the constraint based approaches to Data Flow Analysis and Constraint Based Analysis: in both cases the syntactic structure of the program gives rise to a set of constraints whose least solution is desired. The main difference is that the constraints for the Constraint Based Analysis have a more complex structure than those for the Data Flow Analysis.

I am confused by this part:

> Among other things this tells us that the function abstraction $\text{fn} \ y => y$ is never applied (since $\hat{\rho}(y) = \emptyset$) and that the program may only evaluate to the function abstraction $\text{fn} \ y => y$ (since $\hat{C}(5) = \{ \text{fn} \ y => [y]^3 \}$).

I thought that I understood the program $[[ \text{fn} \ x => [x]^1]^2 [ \text{fn} \ y => [y]^3]^4]^5$. However, this part seems contradictory: it first says that $\text{fn} \ y => y$ is never applied, and it then immediately says that the program may only evaluate to the function abstraction $\text{fn} \ y => y$. Furthermore, I don't understand why, as stated above, "$\text{fn} \ y => y$ is never applied (since $\hat{\rho}(y) = \emptyset$)", and nor do I understand why "the program may only evaluate to the function abstraction $\text{fn} \ y => y$ (since $\hat{C}(5) = \{ \text{fn} \ y => [y]^3 \}$)". For instance, if, as stated above, $\hat{\rho}(y)$ contains the values that the variable $y$ can be bound to, then why is this the empty set (in other words, why can $y$ in the program not be bound to any values)?

I skipped to exercise 1.2 to see if I could gather any additional information:

> **Exercise 1.2** Show that the solution displayed for the Control Flow Analysis in Section 1.4 is a solution. Also show that it is in fact the least solution. (Hint: Consider the demands on $\hat{C}(2)$, $\hat{C}(4)$, $\hat{\rho}(x)$, $\hat{C}(1)$ and $\hat{C}(5)$.)

However, this doesn't really help me make sense of this.

Comment: Have you done any functional programming? Actually writing some functional code (and tracing it with a debugger) may be the best answer to this question.

Comment: Do you undertand that `(fn x ⇒ E₁) E₂` evaluates to `E₁[x:=E₂]` (the expresioon `E₁` with `E₂` substituted for `x`)? What do you get if you use this rule on `(fn x ⇒ x) (fn y ⇒ y)`? And do you undertsand that `(fn x ⇒ E)` does not have an evaluation step, because it is already a value (final result)?

Comment: @AndrejBauer I'm learning the language ML now, but I have so far not seen what you're describing; nor have I seen this described in the textbook in question. If I use the rule you described on `(fn x ⇒ x) (fn y ⇒ y)`, then it seems that I would get `x[x := fn y => y]`, right? So we're assigning the value of `fn y => y` to `x`? But what does the outside `x` in `x[x := fn y => y]` then mean? Also, what does this mean for my question?

Comment: You are trying to understand analysis of functional programs without understanding how functional programs work. I recommend first learning the basics of functional programming.

Comment: You do realize that `x[x := (fn y ⇒ y)]` is the same thing as `fn y ⇒ y`? Because that is what you get if you replace `x` with `(fn y ⇒ y)` in `x`. Also, there are no assignments to variables anywhere. In functional programming we do not assign values to variables. Instead we *replace* variables with expressions.

Comment: Well, you just need to learn the basics to understand the examples in your question. It might be best to just proceed from some language you already do know. Do you know Python by any chance?

Comment: @AndrejBauer I think I found a perfect textbook for this: *Semantics with Applications – An Appetizer* by Hanne Riis Nielson, Flemming Nielson (the same authors). I think the relevant knowledge that I am missing is *formal semantics*.

Comment: Very well! If you're into that sort of thing, you might try out [TAPL](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) or [PFPL](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/pfpl/).

Comment: @AndrejBauer Ok, thanks for the help.